# Image tag inside a button makes the js stop working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button with an image that will toggle a div's class, however, when I use the tag image inside the button, the js won't work. This only happens on chrome, the same code works normally on firefox. Is there any solution to this?

codepen: https://codepen.io/luansergiomattos/pen/zydWyM

html:

```
<div class="bar" style="background-color: #474973; ">
  <br />

  <button id="searchButton">
    <img
      src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-512.png"
      alt=""
      style="width: 20px;"
    />
  </button>
</div>

<div class="bar off but" id="search" style="background-color: #9CEAEF">
  <form action="#">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search.."
      name="search"
      class="header__search"
    />
  </form>
</div>
```

js:

```
var focused = document.querySelector('.header__search'), searchWrapper = document.querySelector('#search'),       
searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchButton'); 

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (~e.target.className.indexOf('header__search')) { 
    searchWrapper.classList.remove('off'); 
    focused.focus(); 
  } else if (~e.target.id.indexOf('searchButton')) { 
    searchWrapper.classList.toggle('off'); 
    focused.focus(); 
  } else { 
    searchWrapper.classList.add('off'); 
  }

});
```

edit: this is what the code is supossed to do: when i press the button, the js will toggle a class, the class named "off" has width: 0px; display: none etc. So the element will be hidden when i press the button, and it will show up again when i press the button. Sorry for any english mistak

Comment: What does "js wont work" mean? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: when i press the button, the js will toggle a class, the class named "off" has      width: 0px; display: none etc. So the element will be hidden when i press the button, and it will show up again when i press the button. Sorry for any english mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is the image becomes the target in your click function – try disable pointer events and it will work again :)

```
button img { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: Wow, that's it! Thanks mate!